# PySpark Kafka streaming on HDInsight - TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub, azure-hdinsight

This is an old question but none of the answers resolved my problem. I am using Azure HDInsight for my Spark cluster and Event Hub for Kafka message broker.

For example, I used exactly same method like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59598505/3134383), and I'm still getting error.

```
'JavaPackage' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 78, in createStream
    helper = KafkaUtils._get_helper(ssc._sc)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 217, in _get_helper
    return sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper()
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

My code is this:

```
import os
sparkVersion = '2.3.2'  # update this accordingly 
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8:{} pyspark-shell'.format(sparkVersion) 

# import Spark core 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
# import extra packages 
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 'hellos.servicebus.windows.net:9093', 'test-group', {'twitter':1})
```

This is my spark version:

```
sc.version
'2.3.2.2.6.5.3026-7'
```

Comment: what version of the Python?

Comment: @AlexOtt It is Python 3.5, which is the default Python3 installation in HDInsight today.

Comment: Looks like an error in the source code for kafka-08 package you got... I suggest you use Structured Streaming instead